# Can I use README files in github pages

Tags: web, github, web-hosting

I am working on a website to host on github, and I want to add README.md file, to let people know what exactly is it.

So is it ok to do that, would that end up in error

Comment: by "hosting on github" you mean GitHub Pages?

Comment: @GregWitczak yes, github pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add a `readme.md` file to any Github repo. Github offers [extensive documentation on how this works](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-readmes).

If I read into your question more deeply, I think what you're really asking is that if you add a readme to a project being hosted on Github pages - will that effect how the hosted website is presented? The answer would be no. In this case, read about how [Github pages hosting works](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/).